# Spinning Artifactory instance (container) during CI pipeline

Tags: docker, image, continuous-integration, pipeline, artifactory

I would like to spin a containerized Artifactory instance, to generate a PyPi repository and publish an artifact... all this in a CI pipeline.

artirfact-oss container image doesn't support PyPi. Any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As PyPi is part of the paid Artifactory subscription, you can consider using a [free Artifactory cloud instance](https://jfrog.com/start-free/#saas).

It has full support of PyPi and other technologies, but is limited by storage and data transfer.

It means you'll have to adjust your automation to reuse this instance and be aware of the limits.

If you have to run it locally, you will probably have to buy a license...

Comment: Assume I have the license. Is it possible to pull artifactory container images? From which container registry?

Comment: Sure! `docker run --name artifactory -d -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro`. See https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-DockerInstallation

Comment: YaY. Thanks Eldad.